# How to catch if cell Value got changed in DataGridView as sender

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, event-handling

I haven't found something that matches my problem so I ask it here. I have some code which belongs to a Textbox:

```
if ((sender as TextBox).Text == form1.filterType())
{
    //Do something
}
```

This comes from the TextBox TextChanged event. So when the TextChanged Event gets fired it calls a method which has the if-construct above and recognizes that the textchanged event came from the textbox.

Now I want exactly the same just when someone writes into a cell in a DataGridView (not when it's just clicked - when the content changes).

How to do this correctly and which event fires when the content changes in a cell without leaving the cell?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {

  this.dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);

 }

 void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
 DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)

    {

     if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)

        {

            TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;

            //"unwire" the event before hooking it up ensures the event handler gets called only once
            tb.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);
            tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);

        }

     }



     void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        MessageBox.Show("changed");

    }
```

Now it fires everytime the value in the cell gets changed - it behaves like a textbox.

Now - I still need a solution for the "if-construct" above. How to do this exactly? I've casted the cell into a textbox but now? Does this still comes from the dataGridview?

Comment: So ok. This events does work but... When I edited a cell and then edit another cell the message pop ups two times in a row. When I edit a third cell then it pop ups three times in a row and so on. Anyone knows how to solve that problem?

Comment: Ok solved this too. I made a boolean variable so that the event is called just one time - then it's set too false. That was the problem....

Comment: You should "unwire" the TextChanged event before hooking it up again. That way it only fires once. I took the liberty of editing your code.

Comment: Thank you! I've done it with a variable which gets set to false after it was fired once

Comment: Yes, I had seen your previous comment, but your solution will prevent further reuse if needed, while mine will allow reuse as needed. Furthermore, "cleaning up" your event handler assignment is always a good thing. Otherwise, even though you have the boolean, the event handler still gets called, and as your application runs for longer, more and more event handlers are getting added, and eventually your boolean is checked hundreds, if not thousands of times. Removing the handler is cleanest.

Comment: Thank you for that. Your solution is better than a variable

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a similar problem an solved it this way (think there are better ones but it worked)

```
private void DataGridView1_onFocus ( Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView1.onKeyPress+=DataGridView1_onKeyStroke;
}
private void DataGridView1_onFocusLost( Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView1.onKeyPress-=DataGridView1_onKeyStroke;
}
private void  DataGridView1_onKeyStroke( Object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    //Do your thing
}
```

Comment: But keystroke events do fire every time when something is changed in the datagridview or not? The solution I posted works fine.

Comment: yes, everytime you press a key (in this case while it has focus).